# App that provides a REST API and a TCP/IP socket interface

Tags: rest, sockets

Is it possible to create an app that provides a REST API and a TCP/IP socket connection interface.  I'm new to web related programming but I do have a REST API demo program working and I have created socket servers in the past.  I need to create an app that can receive messages via a REST API and forward the message to a machine that is connected via the socket connection.   I am working in C# with Visual Studio 2022.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: A REST API is nothing more than a socket server using the HTTP/S protocol for the data. You said yourself that you've written socket servers before. So you basically answered your own question.

Comment: Thank You.  I took a step back and took a fresh look ignoring all of the web stuff I was not familiar with and just proceeded as if this was just a plain old console app.  I was able to get my prototype working.